# Add new value while Create on Scaffold MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a question. I am new on ASP.NET MVC Code First.
I am creating a simple CRUD using Scaffold MVC.

My Model:

```
public class Manufacture
{
    [Key]
    public int ManufactureID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Manufacture", TypeName = "varchar")]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    [Display(Name = "Manufacture")]
    public string ManufactureCode { get; set; }

    [Column("ManufactureDescription", TypeName = "varchar")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string ManufactureDescription { get; set; }

    [Column("IsActive", TypeName = "bit")]
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult ManufactureCreate()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ManufactureCreate([Bind(Include = "ManufactureID,ManufactureCode,ManufactureDescription,IsActive,CreatedDateTime")] Manufacture manufacture)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (db.Manufactures.Any(ac => ac.ManufactureCode.Equals(manufacture.ManufactureCode)))
             {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                db.Manufactures.Add(manufacture);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ManufactureCreate");
            }
        }
        return View(manufacture);
    }
```

I want to add a value on "CreatedDateTime" field using current DateTime. When User click the "Save" button on the View. "CreatedDateTime" field will be filled by current DateTime.

How can I do that?
Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: `manufacture.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now; db.Manufactures.Add(manufacture);` etc. But your editing data so always use a view model - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
manufacture.CreatedDateTime=DateTime.Now;
```

add above the line
`db.Manufactures.Add(manufacture);`

Comment: Try to make controller and view by yourself don't use entity that will help you to learn mvc

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I'm trying too. Can you give me a references?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your else block as below:

```
       else
            {
                manufacture.CreatedDateTime=DateTime.Now;
                db.Manufactures.Add(manufacture);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ManufactureCreate");
            }
```

and yes, you should use ViewModel here as Stephen suggested in the comment.